# new activities from proxies with wurst

Tags: brightway

I'm trying to create a new activity in brightway based on a proxy from other region. I was hopping wurst would do the heavy lifting and connect the datasets to the appropriate markets.

In this example I try to create a market for low pressure natural gas in Quebec using as proxy the Swiss dataset. There is a *market for high pressure natural gas* in Quebec. There is also an intermediate process (pressure reduction) linking the low and high pressure market activities. This is what I did:

```
 #db_name is the name of my consequential version of ecoinvent 3.4
 data= w.extract_brightway2_databases([db_name])

 CH_location = [w.equals('location','CH')]
 pressure_red=[w.equals('name','natural gas pressure reduction from high to low pressure')]

 ch_pressure_red_filter=CH_location+pressure_red
 ch_pred=w.get_one(data,*ch_pressure_red_filter)

 ch_market_lp_ng_filter=CH_location+[w.equals('name','market for natural gas, low pressure')]
 ch_mlp_ng=w.get_one(data,*ch_market_lp_ng_filter)

 #create a copy of the datasets and change location
 qc_mlp_ng=ch_mlp_ng.copy()
 qc_mlp_ng['location']='CA-QC'
 qc_pred=ch_pred.copy()
 qc_pred['location']='CA-QC'
 new_data=[qc_mlp_ng,qc_pred]

 w.write_brightway2_database(data+[qc_mlp_ng,qc_pred],'expanded_ecoinvent')
```

This raises a *NonuniqueCode error* which I guess its because when I created the copy, I have several datasets with the same code. How should this be done to avoid this error? would the procedure re-link all the activities consuming low-pressure natural gas in Quebec to my new market for low pressure NG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating several copies of the dataset while keeping the same unique identifier in the metadata of your dataset.

To avoid this, you can use the built in function `copy_dataset()` from the Wurst python package. This copies the dataset and generates unique uuid codes for each of your copies.

```
from wurst.transformations.utils import copy_dataset
```

`qc_mlp_ng= copy_dataset(ch_mlp_ng)`

`qc_pred=copy_dataset(ch_pred)`